# int? typed property generates a 0 populated column with EF Code First

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a been using Entity Framework code first approach to generate a DB before the application went into a production phase.

Now I have added to following property to one of my entity objects.

```
public virtual int? ClaimIncidentId { get; set; }
```

Then I ran the SQL Migrations to automatically update the database so it would conform with the current entity declarations.

This has resulted in generation of a Column in the corresponding table. The column name is `ClaimIncidentId`, but the default value, that got populated for each existing row was `0`, not `null`.

How could I have explicitly let the SQL Migrations to generate a `null` valued column. Other then an actual value, column is decleared as nullable, so theoretically, it should have put `null`s in it.

Comment: How did your migration configuration look like? Did you manually add anything to `Up` method or changed default value for the new column in `AddColumn`? If not try to do that.

Comment: Ok, thanks, as soon as I find `AddColumn`, I will try. Thanks. My configuration is what get's created by default when I install EF4.3 beta with NuGet. I just set EnableAutomaticMigration to true and do no other adjustments, since the change I am introducing seems so simple to me.